# setuid flag doesn't change the effective userid

Tags: terminal

Here I have a file called `uid_demo.c`, which displays the real userid and the effective userid.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("real uid: %d\n", getuid());
    printf("effective uid: %d\n", geteuid());
}
```

And I ran the following commands:

```
gcc -o uid_demo uid_demo.c
sudo chown root:root ./uid_demo
sudo chmod u+s ./uid_demo
ls -l uid_demo
```

Output:

```
-rwsrwxr-x 1 root root 8712 Jun 29 15:09 uid_demo
```

When I run the program, it should display my real userid (1000) and the effective userid of 0 (root), as the owner of the file is root and the setuid permission is turned on. However, it displays the following:

```
real uid: 1000
effective uid: 1000
```

Any help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably running the program on a filesystem that is mounted wit the `nosuid` flag, thus your setuid bit is not respected.

Move your code to another location on the filesystem that does not have this, or disable the nosuid flag in the mount options for the current filesystem.

The nosuid flag is a security feature.